# JAVA: using maps with the value as an array list of string

Tags: java

This code prompts the user asking their name and the school they attend. Storing both into a map. I then want to print out the school and the name of every person that attended that school in this format.

School : name, name , name. /new line
School : name, name , name etc.
.
.
.

However I keep getting null values for the name when trying to print 
here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class MapsAndArrayList {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        String school;
        String name;
        //create the map with Arraylist as key value
        Map<String, ArrayList<String>> sAtt = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>();


        do {

            System.out.println("Enter your name: (type \"done\" when done)");
            name = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            System.out.println("Enter the school you attend: ");
            school = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();

            if (!sAtt.containsKey(school)) { // if school is not already in list, add it 
                ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
                //add name to arraylist of names
                names.add(name);
                sAtt.put(school, names);
            } else { // if school is in list just add name to list
                ArrayList<String> names = sAtt.get(school);
                names.add(name);
                sAtt.replace(school, names);
            }

        } while (!(name.equals("DONE") || school.equals("DONE")));
        // remove done from the list
        sAtt.remove("DONE");

        System.out.println("Here are the schools attended along with who goes there: ");

        for (String s : sAtt.keySet()) {
            System.out.println("\t" + s + ": " + sAtt.get(school));
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The last for loop is using wrong key. Following would be right for loop:

```
for (String s : sAtt.keySet()) {
    System.out.println("\t" + s + ": " + sAtt.get(s));
}
```

You are getting null because school variable has DONE as key which is removed in earlier statement.

Also, I would suggest using multi-map for this purpose.
https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html